# Adding and configuring a WFS service in Geocortex essentials

Tags: wms, wfs, geocortex, services, geocortex-essentials

I need to add a WFS service to Geocortex essentials and view it the HTML-5 Viewer, I could add a WMS service and view it as a PNG image, still, I need to attach this WMS service to it's WFS capability so I can perform  the features the WFS offers.

What I've been thinking of is:

1. from "service connection", choose "add connection" and then choose a WFS service from the drop down list, the thing is that what is the correct 
   URL I should provide?? shall I put the whole thing with GetCapabilities, GetFeatureType ... or WHAT?? what is the correct URL I should provide??
   [image]
   [image]
2. I tried to edit my WMS service through the Query Builder, from the details tab, choose "edit connection settings" and then enter the WFS-URL:
   [image]
   [image]

Now, even though I was able to perform the two options, when I start the HTML5 viewer, it shows me an alert saying that "one of the layers can't be added ..." I don't know what's the issue, Geocortex support site showed me nothing, and I'm almost hopeless since I've been trying for so long and don't know even from whaere to start.

Anyone with knowledge in Geocortex can maybe help me

Comment: Generally the URL that you should specify for any client (unless instructed otherwise) is the service endpoint, normally something like: `http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wfs?` note you should include the question mark.   The client would use this endpoint to append any request parameters. such as request=GetFeature& version=1.1.0& ...

Comment: `The version is detected automatically` might be causing you problems.  The sedac service supports up to version 2.0.0, and a GetCapabilites request without version specified will give a 2.0.0 response.  Does ArcGIS support this version?  did you try specifying the WFS version as  1.1.0